# X linked traits expression in females

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, gene-expression

We all know that females have an inactivated X chromosome (Most of its genes are inactivated).
Consider a female who is a heterozygous carrier of an X linked abnormality,
If the inactivated X was that carrying the normal gene, shouldn't the abnormality be expressed in this female? Why is it not expressed even though the other X is inactivated?

Answer (score 4):

Because in different cells different copies of the X chromosome might be inactivated. 
So, in (approximately) 50% of the cells you will have the X carrying the normal gene activated, and in the remaining 50% you will have the other.
You might start reading something [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-inactivation), and then go in further detail to understand. A nice article is [here](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/x-chromosome-x-inactivation-323)